# How to do a source route to a proxy server?

Tags: routing, proxy, ip, router

I have:

- A router with an IP set to 192.168.8.1
- ComputerA with IP 192.168.8.11
- A Proxy server with IP 192.168.8.102

My network 192.168.8.0/24. gateway 192.168.8.1

I want to route ALL traffic from ComputerA to the Proxy server.

I had try adding a new rule but not luck.

Here the steps that i follow:

```
#ip rule list
0:      from all lookup local
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

.

```
# ip route show table main
default via 72.xxx.0.1 dev eth0
10.8.8.0/24 via 10.8.8.2 dev tun21
10.8.8.2 dev tun21  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.8.1
72.xxx.0.0/21 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 72.xxx.1.31
72.xxx.0.1 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link
127.0.0.0/8 dev lo  scope link
192.168.8.0/24 dev br0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.8.1
239.0.0.0/8 dev br0  scope link
```

Then I add the rule:

```
ip rule add from 192.168.8.11 table 11
```

Then the route:

```
ip route add default via 192.168.8.102 dev br0 table 11 metric 1
```

I make sure the changes are there:

```
#  ip rule list
0:      from all lookup local
32765:  from 192.168.8.11 lookup 11
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default

#  ip route show table 11
default via 192.168.8.102 dev br0  metric 1
```

But, does not seams to be working...
Any idea of what am I doing wrong?
Thanks.

Here some extra info:

```
# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 brd 127.255.255.255 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ifb0: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 32
    link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:66 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: ifb1: <BROADCAST,NOARP> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 32
    link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:77 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: imq0: <NOARP> mtu 16000 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 11000
    link/void
5: imq1: <NOARP> mtu 16000 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 11000
    link/void
6: imq2: <NOARP> mtu 16000 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 11000
    link/void
7: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
8: ip6tnl0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1452 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/tunnel6 :: brd ::
9: ip6gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1448 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/gre6 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00
10: archer: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
11: bcmsw: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
12: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 72.xxx.xxx.xxx/21 brd 72.xxx.xxx.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
14: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
15: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
16: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
17: spu_us_dummy: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
18: spu_ds_dummy: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
19: dpsta: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
20: eth5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
21: eth6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d4:5d:64:c6:4b:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
26: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,ALLMULTI,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.8.1/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
27: tun21: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 100
    link/none
    inet 10.8.8.1 peer 10.8.8.2/32 scope global tun21
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Frames on the same network are delivered directly from host to host. The packets are encapsulated in the frames, so they are not routed, and IP does not come into play except on the source and destination hosts. Switches do not look at the packets or addresses on the packets, they switch frames by MAC addresses on the frames. You are trying to do this with IP addressing, but that has no effect on the same network.

Comment: what is the output in you run `route` and `ip addr`? and are you sure your proxy is actually forwards traffic?

Comment: @RonMaupin so why does work when I add a rule in the main table? like this:  # ip route add 1.2.3.4/24 via 192.168.8.102 dev br0  metric 1 table main

Comment: That is for routing, which is between networks. Traffic on the same network stays on the same network, and it does not pass through a router. Routers route traffic _between_ networks.

Comment: @Tch I just added.